# Can not set default ruby version from Ansible duo to the bash environment

Tags: ruby, rvm, ansible

I am using Ansible to setup RVM, Ruby and I got some issues with the path of RVM.

I also check from Ansible Galaxy and learn from this example https://github.com/newmen/ansible-rvm/blob/master/tasks/select_ruby.yml

I want to set the default ruby version

```
- name: set using ruby 2.1.1 by default
  shell: "{{ rvm_path }}/rvm use {{ ruby_ver }} --default executable=/bin/bash"
```

Or even

```
- name: set using ruby 2.1.1 by default
  shell: "source /home/ubuntu/.rvm/scripts/rvm && source /home/ubuntu/.profile && {{ rvm_path }}/rvm use {{ ruby_ver }} --default executable=/bin/bash"
```

But it all returns

```
"stderr": "RVM is not a function, selecting rubies with 'rvm use ...' will not work.\n\nYou need to change your terminal emulator preferences to allow login shell.\nSometimes it is required to use `/bin/bash --login` as the command
```

I understand that somehow Ansible can not load the bash environment so it can not fully use `rvm` function.

I tried with Ansible `1.9.x` and also the latest `2.x` but they don't work.

Which params or tweak should I use?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Why not run `bash --login -c 'your rvm command'`, so in your example:

```
- name: set using ruby 2.1.1 by default
  shell: "/bin/bash --login -c '{{ rvm_path }}/rvm use {{ ruby_ver }} --default executable=/bin/bash'"
```

Comment: Your solution works. Now I'm using `- command: "{{ rvm_path }}/rvm alias create default ruby-{{ ruby_ver }}"` and it works too. It is annoying with the bash env.